# how to install a package in a pod

Tags: kubernetes-pod

Exploring deployments in Kubernetes, I'm trying to understand what is the appropriate method to  `apt-get update && apt-get install some_package -y`  on a pod.

Been trying so far but with no luck the following:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gitlab-runner
          image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding
          command: ["/bin/bash", "/scripts/entrypoint", "apt-get", "update"]
          args: ["apt-get", "install", "packer", "-y"]
```

and

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gitlab-runner
          image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding
          command: ["/bin/bash", "/scripts/entrypoint", "apt-get", "update"]
          command: ["apt-get", "install", "packer", "-y"]
```

and

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gitlab-runner
          image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding
          command: ["/bin/bash", "/scripts/entrypoint", "apt-get", "install", "packer", "-y"]]
```

**Questions are:**

1. What is the right method to have a pod ( ubuntu based container ) updated and with a package installed?
2. Is it ok to do it via a deployment or should it be via a configmap?
3. What's the right method if let's say you need to install and configure multiple packages?

I know I could you helm, but before going into that, I'd rather prefer properly understanding it without helm.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, got my answer by pushing further:

these commands -> `apt-get update && apt-get install packer -y` must be added to config-map.yaml. Something like this:

```
data:

  entrypoint: |
    #!/bin/bash

    set -xe
    apt-get update && apt-get install packer -y
    .
    .
    .
```

Then you create the config-map

And then you just create your deployment pointing to the config map.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share how you connected the deployment to the configmap.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can install packages using the container entrypoint, you will take an installation hit every time a pod starts/restarts. This is fine for troubleshooting, another approach if you're troubleshooting is exec into the pod and run the same commands, then you have a shell -

```bash
kubectl exec -it container-name -- sh
apt-get update
apt-get install packer -y
```

Generally, if this is meant to be a long-term solution (and performance matters at all), I'd recommend building, publishing and referencing your own image using a Dockerfile based on the image you've referenced - `gitlab/gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding`

For example - 
`Dockerfile`

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y packer
#...
ENTRYPOINTY ['/somescript.sh']
```

```
docker build --tag my-repo/my-gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding-edge .
docker push my-repo/my-gitlab-runner:ubuntu-bleeding-edge
```

Then reference your custom image from your pod or deployment yaml manifest.

Now you won't take the performance hit of installing the package every time your pod starts, it's handled at build time.