# kubernetes: how to install a package in a pod's container during container creation

Tags: kubernetes

I'm taking the beginner kubernetes course at Udemy.

I'm trying (as an educational task) to install any arbitrary package on a container solely using command/args elements.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: curl-nginx
  name: curl-nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: curl-nginx
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - apk update;
    - apk upgrade;
    - apk add curl;
    - while true; do curl nginx-loadbalancer >> /tmp/curl.txt 2>&1 ; done;
  restartPolicy: Always
```

But the pod is not executing the while loop even though it is executing the apk commands (as proven by logs):

```
 $ kc logs curl-nginx
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.18.4-8-g72c62a84ddf [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main]
v3.18.4-7-g75aa72add9b [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community]
OK: 19941 distinct packages available
```

The failure I'm seeing (from kc describe pod):

```
  Warning  BackOff    2s (x3 over 21s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container curl-nginx in pod curl-nginx_dev(613a7fa7-952a-4d2a-b226-df87aa866f06)
```

And I don't know why k8s is not executing the while loop.

Please note, I know this (the above) is not the recommended PROD method and best to (and I already did both of them successfully):

1. create a new image with pre-loaded packages; OR
2. exec into the container and manually install them.

So please don't make either of those or other suggestions.

I am trying to install the pkgs in the command/args section as an exercise to gain better understanding of how commands are used. Hence, I want to learn what's wrong with my while loop syntax.

In addition, a third option was sited in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246407/how-to-install-a-package-in-a-pod) but I can NOT figure out how to connect the configmap to the pod and the aforementioned thread isn't helpful. However, I'm still leaning toward figuring out the solution solely based on using command/args.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: curl-nginx-cm
data:
  entrypoint: |
    #!/bin/bash
    set -xe
    apk update
    apk upgrade
    apk add curl
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: curl-nginx
  name: curl-nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: curl-nginx
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - while true; do curl nginx-loadbalancer >> /tmp/curl.txt 2>&1 ; done;
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying (as an educational task) to install any arbitrary package on a container solely using command/args elements.

I would argue that this is an anti-pattern: if you need specific packages for your service, you should be building appropriate images and pushing those to a registry, and then creating deployments using your custom images.

---

You have errors in your `args` configuration. Remember that the `sh -c` command takes a single argument -- the script to be executed. When you write this:

```
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - apk update;
    - apk upgrade;
    - apk add curl;
    - while true; do curl nginx-loadbalancer >> /tmp/curl.txt 2>&1 ; done;
```

You are writing:

```
sh -c 'apk update;' 'apk upgrade;' 'apk add curl;' '...etc...'
```

Try running that at the command line and you'll see that it runs the `pk update` command...and ignores everything else. Generally, if you want to run a shell script when the Pod starts, you would do something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: curl-nginx
  name: curl-nginx
spec:
  restartPolicy: Always
  containers:
  - image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    name: curl-nginx
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      apk update
      apk upgrade
      apk add curl
      while true; do
        curl nginx-loadbalancer >> /tmp/curl.txt 2>&1
      done
```

This uses the YAML block literal quote (`|`) to pass the included script -- preserving newlines -- as the argument to `sh -c`.

> In addition, a third option was sited in thread but I can NOT figure out how to connect the configmap to the pod...

This is covered explicitly [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap).

---

Regarding `command` vs `args`:

The args are passed as arguments to command. Most container images have a default command that will receive your args, but in this case we don't care what the image does by default; we want to run a shell script. We can just override command.

With that in mind, we could rewrite the above manifest like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: curl-nginx
  name: curl-nginx
spec:
  restartPolicy: Always
  containers:
  - image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    name: curl-nginx
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    args:
      -|
        apk update
        apk upgrade
        apk add curl
        while true; do
          curl nginx-loadbalancer >> /tmp/curl.txt 2>&1
        done
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Your "You are writing:" taught me not only what's wrong but how to fault-proof the cmd element in the future.
I didn't know about the command format. Thanks again. 
I am confused when to use args vs command. Seems I can use each individually or one after the other.

Comment: I've updated the answer to discuss `command` vs `args`. See also https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: `args:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          apk update
          apk upgrade
          apk add curl
          while true; do
            curl nginx-loadbalancer >> /tmp/curl.txt 2>&1
          done` 
behaves exactly the same as if I replaced `args` with `command`. Hence, the confusion :)